# Trouble with the combat sections in Heavy Rain

Tags: heavy-rain

In the odd occasion I find myself having to get involved in a fight I always end up getting my ass handed too me. I find switching from the normal motion and action controls to responding to fast quick time prompts very tricky.

How can I react better? Is there any sort of pattern to the type of motions you're asked to do?

Comment: what difficulty level are you playing on?

Comment: Also, are you playing with DualShock or the Motion Controller ?

Comment: Dual Shock. I've yet to be convinced Move is worth getting, especially as I'm mainly a FPS player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what has been mentioned, there is also a mode where you specify that you are new to games `"Easy - I play video games occasionally"` and it gives you more time per action and is a little bit more lenient with accidental buttons.

For the sake of completeness, I felt that the game is significantly harder and tiring with the motion controller, the actions are closer to what you would do in real life but it takes getting used to. So if you want to go that route then you have to try try again.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that in a lot of scenes, following the correct prompts or close to it would still get you slapped pretty badly. A lot of the fights look "almost lost" but then you get one saving grace at the end (the doc fight is a good example, I actually restarted twice not realizing hat it wasn't over).

I think that it only hurt me in the last fight.

Not sure if there's a way to react faster-  except replay replay replay. If you play on easy, the prompts are almost always the same.

Comment: I think I'm the only person who never fought the Doc...when he left the room I took a quick look around and got the hell out of dodge.

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there any sort of pattern to the type of motions you're asked to do?"*

Not really. The quick-time actions are meant to approximate the actions of the characters on screen.

Not being very good at the fight sequences isn't really a problem though! The game continues no matter what the result of the fight is. So do the best you can, then sit back and let the story continue.

Comment: I keep wondering if I'm missing branches in the story when I keep ending up on the floor.

Comment: The story might be branching at those points, but the story branches anyway. You're not really missing any more than you would if you won the fights - you'd just be seeing a different outcome. Heavy Rain was designed to be like an interactive movie (or choose-your-own-adventure book) where your actions affect how the story unfolds.

Comment: The game continues, but your characters start dying - depends if you care about keeping people alive for an "optimal" ending.  For instance, if you fail all the action sequences, you will not be able to save Sean.

Comment: Okay, so he might not be able to achieve the Hollywood happy ending, but that doesn't make his playthrough invalid - it's still an acceptable playthrough of the game. The game designers' goal was to give every player their own experience. If you have an answer that will help him get better at the QTEs, please post it.